# Wordpress Pagination in a Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

A quick question for the Wordpress Brains out there ...

Ive got a shortcode which currently imports all posts from a certain post type. However Im having trouble adding pagination to the wp_query.

To explain once this code functions, I put [feed type="attractions" limit="2"] on the page and it displays 2 posts based on attractions, however it doesnt paginate. Just wondering what im doing wrong exactly...

Heres the code! --- >

```
    function section_feed_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => -1, 'type' => 'post'), $atts ) );

    $q = new WP_Query(  array ( 'posts_per_page' => $limit, 'post_type' => $type, order => 'ASC', orderby =>'menu_order', 'paged' => get_query_var('page')  ) );

    $list = ' ';

    while ( $q->have_posts() ) { $q->the_post();

        $list .= '<article class="listing-view clearfix">' 
        . '<div class="listing-content">' 
        . '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3>' 
        .'<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>'
        . '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . 'View &raquo;' . '</a>'
        . '</div>'
        . '<a class="listing-thumb" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'listing-thumb')  . '<span></span></a>'
        . '</article>';
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    return 
    '<div class="listings clearfix">' 
    . $list 
    . '<div class="nav-previous">' . next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'stratford_wp' ) ) . '</div>'
    . '<div class="nav-next">' . previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'stratford_wp' ) ) . '</div>'
    . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'feed', 'section_feed_shortcode' );
```

Thanks for answers in advanced!

Answer (score 6):

faced that problem today and got a solution :

```
global $paged
$q = new WP_Query(  array ( 'posts_per_page' => $limit, 'post_type' => $type, order => 'ASC', orderby =>'menu_order', 'paged' => $paged  ) );
```

And then you have to change the `paginate_links` query for your custom post. see [wp codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Example_With_a_Custom_Query) example. Better you can add a function and call it before `wp_reset_query()` and within the function use

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
   'format' => '?paged=%#%',
   'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
   'total' => $q->max_num_pages //$q is your custom query
 ) );
```

Comment: Still rocks on 2023, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting your query before you get to the next/previous links. What happens if you move the wp_reset_query() function further down?

Also, you might have more luck with this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Dalton, tried moving the reset function down and this had no effect.

I've reposted this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58880/shortcode-displaying-custom-post-types

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add global $paged and then in your array that is being passed to WP_Query you need to add 'paged' => $paged

Your query should like this.

```
global $paged
$q = new WP_Query(  array ( 'posts_per_page' => $limit, 'post_type' => $type, order => 'ASC', orderby =>'menu_order', 'paged' => $paged  ) );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to change anything. Its not that pagination doesn't work... when I type in the url and "/page/2" it does display the next set of posts, however the get_next_posts_link and previous link doesn't seem to be pulling in anything.