# Category listing pages for Custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I added the custom post type to my theme named Projects. It's using built in **category** taxonomy but can't get those project categories posts listed on front end.

Here is my the code that I used for creating the custom post type

```
// Register Custom Post Type
```

function custom_post_type() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                => 'Projects',
    'singular_name'       => 'Project',
    'menu_name'           => 'Projects',
    'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Item:',
    'all_items'           => 'All Items',
    'view_item'           => 'View Item',
    'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Item',
    'add_new'             => 'Add New',
    'edit_item'           => 'Edit Item',
    'update_item'         => 'Update Item',
    'search_items'        => 'Search Item',
    'not_found'           => 'Not found',
    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Not found in Trash',
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'projects',
    'description'         => 'Project Description',
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'projects', $args );
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query for your post type like: `$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=projects' );`

I'd even recommend that you create a shortcode for your post type, that does the custom query and lists the posts.

You can find out more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Comment: Thanks flowb0b. Will querying like this broke regular paging that's already part of the theme or I can continue using existing one?

Comment: I'd suggest adding your pagination inside your shortcode. Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430392/wordpress-pagination-in-a-shortcode