# Adding pagination to wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

Following advice on [Wordpress Pagination in a Shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430392/wordpress-pagination-in-a-shortcode) I'm working on a shortcode for wordpress and trying to add pagination to it. I'm almost there, just don't know why wordpress isn't updating paginated pages content, e.g. if I click on "Next" or "1", "2", "3" etc I always see the same page.

**This is my code**:

```
function carforyou_LatestCar($atts){
ob_start();?>
<div class="row">
    <?php 
    extract( shortcode_atts(array('show' =>''), $atts ));   
    extract( shortcode_atts(array('brand' =>''), $atts ));
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(    
    'post_type' => 'auto',  
    'auto-brand' => $brand, 
    'posts_per_page'=>$show, 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'offset' => 0     
));
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    global $paged; ?>
        <div class="col-list-3">
          <div class="featured-car-list">
                <div class="featured-car-img">
                    <a alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):
                                the_post_thumbnail('carforyou_small', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
                                else:
                                echo "<div class='is-empty-img-box'></div>";
                                endif;
                         ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php carforyou_AutoType(); ?>
                    <div class="compare_item">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <button id="compare_auto_btn" onclick="<?php echo esc_js('javascript:productCompare('.$post->ID.')'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Compare','carforyou'); ?></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
                <div class="featured-car-content">
                    <h6><a title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo mb_strimwidth($title, 0, 30, '...'); ?></a></h6>
                    <div class="price_info">
                        <?php  if(!empty($post->DREAM_auto_price)): ?>
                        <p class="featured-price"><?php carforyou_curcy_prefix(); ?><?php echo number_format_i18n(esc_html($post->DREAM_auto_price)); ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="car-location">
                        <?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'auto-location', array("fields" => "all"));
                                foreach($term_list as $term_single) 
                                    $location = $term_single->name;
                        ?>
                        <?php  if(!empty($location)): ?>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo esc_html($location); ?> </span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <?php carforyou_featuredList(); ?> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>   
    <?php endwhile; 
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
   'format' => '?paged=%#%',
   'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
   'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
 ) );

    wp_reset_query(); 
    ?>   
</div>
<?php }
```

Any advice? :)
Thank you!

Comment: I don't see where `$paged` is defined in your code so chances are that's the reason why your pagination doesn't work. Try adding `global $paged;` at the top of your code (right before `ob_start();`) and give it another shot.

Comment: I have added global `$paged;` right before `ob_start();` unfurtunately I still can't get pagination working. I can click on "Next", "Previous" or selected pages e.g. "1", "2", "3" etc, but the paginated pages content is still same.

Answer (score 0):

add in functions.php

```html
// Numbered Pagination
    if ( !function_exists( 'kris_pagination' ) ) {
     
     function kris_pagination() {
      
      $prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '→' : '←';
      $next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '←' : '→';
      
      global $wp_query;
      $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
      $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
      if( $total > 1 )  {
        if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
         $current_page = 1;
        if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
         $format = 'page/%#%/';
        } else {
         $format = '&paged=%#%';
        }
       echo paginate_links(array(
        'base'   => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format'  => $format,
        'current'  => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total'   => $total,
        'mid_size'  => 3,
        'type'    => 'list',
        'prev_text'  => $prev_arrow,
        'next_text'  => $next_arrow,
        ) );
      }
     }
     
    }
```

shortcode

```html
<?php kris_pagination(); ?>
```

Comment: I have added your code to function.php unfurtunately I still can't get pagination working. I can click on "Next", "Previous" or selected pages e.g. "1", "2", "3" etc, but the paginated pages content is still same.

Comment: chk this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185600/pagination-not-working

Comment: Thanks mate, sorted. Please add this as an answer and I will accept it :)